# How can I combine these two queries such that the results are in one table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

First query:

```
SELECT integration_department_map.foreign_department_key AS 'Department Code', department.department_name AS 'Department Name'
FROM integration_department_map
JOIN department ON department.department_id = integration_department_map.department_id
WHERE integration_department_map.client_id = '10134';
```

Second query:

```
SELECT integration_department_map.foreign_department_key AS 'Department Code', location.location_name AS 'Location Name'
FROM integration_department_map
JOIN location ON location.location_id = integration_department_map.location_id
WHERE integration_department_map.client_id = '10134';
```

They both return the results needed separately, but I want to know if there is a way they could be written as one query?

Comment: Just join `location` in your first query too, and you can select `location.location_name`. You should use table aliases to help readability of your code.

Comment: Yes I did this as I thought the same. However it returns empty set when written as one query this way.

Comment: Please add some sample data that reflects the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is a LEFT JOIN and not a JOIN (inner join). How many lines in the original integration_department_map satisfy the WHERE clause, and are they the same lines?

maybe this will do the trick -

```
SELECT 
    i.id,
    i.foreign_department_key AS `Department Code`, 
    d.department_name AS `Department Name`, 
    l.location_name AS `Location Name`
FROM integration_department_map i
LEFT JOIN department d ON d.department_id = i.department_id
LEFT JOIN location l   ON l.location_id = i.location_id
WHERE i.client_id = 10134
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [honeybadger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1587819/honeybadger) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72718999/how-can-i-combine-these-two-queries-such-that-the-results-are-in-one-table#comment128447341_72718999). Just add a `join` to location table like:

```sql
SELECT 
    i.foreign_department_key AS `Department Code`, 
    d.department_name AS `Department Name`, 
    l.location_name AS `Location Name`
FROM integration_department_map i
JOIN department d
ON d.department_id = i.department_id
JOIN location l
ON l.location_id = i.location_id
WHERE i.client_id = 10134
```

And remove quotes around `id` if it's an `int` as it should be.

Comment: I have already tried this and for some reason it returns Empty set. I thought this would be the way to do it as well, but for some reason it will not return anything.

Comment: And your 2 query's do return results?

Comment: Yes! Which is why this is most bizarre. I am fairly new to SQL so I just wanted to ask here and see if I was just making a dumb mistake.

Comment: Did you copy my query as it is? Because maybe for some reason the id is a string

Comment: I've tried both ways and it does not make a difference.

Comment: I also added double quotes around column names. Is this the problem? As I'm not using `mysql` so maybe you should use backticks. Does your query return desired results?